# iPhone: Is there a pre-made UISettingsView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

On startup, if the user hasn't done any setting of NSUserDefaults, I want my main view to do a flipside view that brings up the same stuff that shows up in the Settings app.

Is there an API for instantiating the same controller that Settings uses, or will I have to reimplement a table view and controller myself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This website](http://blog.nottoobadsoftware.com/tag/mysettings/) hosts the 'MySettings' API which is a nice toolkit that encapsulates various Settings features (switches, choices, etc) all in a declarative (plist-based) API.

Comment: That looks like exactly what I was searching for.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to code the ui elements yourself if you wish to make the perferences available within your app.  The utility template in xcode gives you a starting point by making a flipview available.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Craig Hockenberry's [Generic Table Views](http://furbo.org/2009/04/30/matt-gallagher-deserves-a-medal/), which make it really easy to set up a Settings-like table view.

Comment: This one looks interesting too, but MySettings seems closest to what I was going for.